# Getting "ProgressEvent" Instead of json from response in Angular + NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Here is my get function in my message.service

**message.service.ts**

```
addMessage(message: Message) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(message);
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/messages', body, { headers: headers })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        const result = response.json();
        const message = new Message(result.obj.title, result.obj.content, 'Dummy', result.obj._id, null);
        this.messages.push(message);
        return message;
      })
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
```

And here is in my backend. If the user is not loggedin. It will return an error (Unauthorized).

**routes/messages.js**

```
router.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  jwt.verify(req.query.token, 'secret', (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        title: 'Not Authenticated',
        error: err
      });
    }
    next();
  });
});
```

And some posts says that it's related to CORS.
But I have this on my backend too.

**app.js**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});
app.use('/messages', messageRoutes);
app.use('/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api', appRoutes);
```

And this is in my component.

**message-input.component.ts**

```
this.messageService.addMessage(message)
          .subscribe(
          data => this.snackBar.open('Your message is added!', 'Success!', {duration: 3000, extraClasses: ['success-snackbar']}),
          error => console.error(error)
          );
```

When there's an error because of authorization. The error is not the one I return from my backend. Instead it's this "Progress Event"

```
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
```

I want to know how to show the error from my backend in json format. The error that should show to my console log.

Comment: I am running my backend at localhost:3000 and my angular at localhost:4200. I tried mixing them so that I will just to run localhost:3000. Everything's working.

Comment: But how to I fix the problem if I'm running my backend at localhost:3000 and angular at localhost:4200.

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue. I added a new middleware into my asp net core app to return a custom response in certain conditions. The custom response ended up being always that ProgressEvent like yours. As soon as I moved my middleware to afterwards the CORS middleware, it started working fine. Maybe your issue is similar to mine but in NodeJS